# Timeouts + Prepared Transactions with ADO.NET / Npgsql

Tags: ado.net, npgsql, transactionscope

Looking for some clarification on the below scenarios. `CanAddConcurrently`  and `DoesNotTimeout`  are failing.

`CanAddConcurrently` - (Npgsql.PostgresException: 55000: prepared transactions are disabled). I understand it's because I have this disabled in my postgres config, but WHY is this escalating to a prepared transaction? Is it because it's actually getting a different NpgsqlConnection? If so, does this really call for a distributed transaction? I can run the same sample with knex, node-postgres with same pool limits, prepared transactions disabled in postgres without issue under node.js

`DoesNotTimeout` - (The connection pool has been exhausted) I don't understand why the pooled connections are not being reused here. Are they not being disposed because they are associated with the top level TransactionScope in the test? Even under this scenario why can't the connection be reused if it's associated with the same transaction. I can run the same test case with knex, node-postgres with the same pool limit without issue under node.js.

```cs
using Npgsql;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Transactions;

namespace TestCases
{
    public class Service
    {
        private readonly string connectionString;

        public Service(string connectionString)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        // I am aware this is only executing 1 query so does not have a need for an embedded transaction, this is just to keep example simple
        // removing the TransactionScope does not fix the issue, but for closer sample to original code it is here
        public async Task Add(string val)
        {
            using (var nestedScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();

                var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO data(value) values(@p);", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p", val);

                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                nestedScope.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Npgsql;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Transactions;

namespace TestCases
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ServiceTests
    {
        readonly string connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=test_db;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;MaxPoolSize=10;Pooling=true;";
        private Service service;

        [TestInitialize]
        public async Task Initialize()
        {
            service = new Service(this.connectionString);

            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();

                var query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(value varchar(255));";
                var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);

                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public async Task Cleanup()
        {
            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();

                var query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data;";
                var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);

                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Failing with prepared PG 55000 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task CanAddConcurrently()
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(
                    Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(async i =>
                    {
                        var val = string.Format("CanAddConcurrently_Q{0};", i);
                        await service.Add(val);
                    })
                );

                scope.Complete();
            }

            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();

                var query = "select count(*) from data WHERE value like 'CanAddConcurrently_Q%';";
                var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);

                long count = (long)await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

                Assert.AreEqual((long)100, count);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Timing out
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task DoesNotTimeout()
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(
                    Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(async i =>
                    {
                        var val = string.Format("DoesNotTimeout_Q{0};", i);
                        await service.Add(val);
                    })
                );

                scope.Complete();
            }

            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();

                var query = "select count(*) from data WHERE value like 'DoesNotTimeout_Q%';";
                var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);

                long count = (long)await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

                Assert.AreEqual((long)100, count);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Passes OK
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task CanAddSequentially()
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    var val = string.Format("CanAddSequentially_Q{0};", i);
                    await service.Add(val);
                }

                scope.Complete();
            }

            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();

                var query = "select count(*) from data WHERE value like 'CanAddSequentially_Q%';";
                var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);

                long count = (long)await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

                Assert.AreEqual((long)100, count);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Passes OK
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task RollsBackIfError()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
                {
                    for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        var val = string.Format("RollsBackIfError_Q{0};", i);

                        if (i == 99)
                        {
                            val = val.PadRight(300, 'e'); // trigger error on last item
                        }

                        await service.Add(val);
                    }

                    scope.Complete();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.IsInstanceOfType(ex, typeof(NpgsqlException));
            }

            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();

                var query = "select count(*) from data WHERE value like 'RollsBackIfError_Q%';";
                var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);

                long count = (long)await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

                Assert.AreEqual((long)0, count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand exactly how `Task.WhenAll()` (and possibly async) operates.

Your code above invokes `Service.Add()` 10 times, *concurrently*, on the same transaction scope, and then waits for those 10 invocations to complete. Each invocation opens a new pooled connection and attempts to enlist to the single transaction scope that exists in your program; the moment more than one connection is enlisted to a transaction scope, that is a distributed transaction, which is why the escalation occurs.

The same likely explains the pool exhaustion in your second example - it's not about pool connections not being *reused*, it's about you trying to use too many *at the same time*.

You should run your code serially with a standard foreach, executing the next operation only after the previous one completed. It is possible to run multiple operations at the same time - for better performance - but you definitely can't share the same transaction scope between them.

Comment: I get that they are all running at the same time in Task.WhenAll. The timeout example is waiting 15 seconds (default) before erroring out and an insert to a local database should only take a few ms, so I'm still a little confused as to why it isn't grabbing one of the pooled connections, even if they are all tied into the same transaction. Is it awaiting the command execution or the scope.complete that would be blocking that connection and preventing the other concurrent invocations from getting a connections?

Comment: I also did dig into our nodejs stuff a bit more and it seems like it ensures that when a query is tagged to a specific transaction, internally it makes sure the same connection from it's pool is used. Is that type of coordination something that would be included in bug #1378 or that can't happen because a connection is fetched from the pool manually without context before any query is ever executed?

Comment: It is indeed grabbing pooled connections, but the moment you associate two connections to the same transaction scope, you're asking for a distributed transaction to get created. I have no idea what nodejs does, but what exactly do you expect would happen? In theory a driver could detect a 2nd open on a transaction scope, and then block until the 1st connection is done, but why would we want that behavior? Doesn't it make more sense for you to code that yourself, i.e. not open two connections in the same transaction scope?

Comment: #1378 has nothing to do with it - it's about implementing distributed transactions in a more reliable way (with recovery). Yes, we don't always know when a connection is open that you're going to enlist it to an already-in-use transaction scope (anyone can call DbConnectio.Enlist() at any point). We also don't want to block actual legitimate use of distributed transactions, which is what you seem to be asking for (even if for now distributed transactions don't work in .NET Core, only .NET Framework)

Comment: tl;dr write your program in a way that expresses what you actually want to do. If you want a single, non-distributed transaction, simply execute all operations on a single connection that has that transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm not trying to get around distributed transactions, I was just trying to understand what the difference in implementations was, and why one was trying to utilize DTs. I understand that now with your confirmation. My goal is to tie `Service` back to and interface with a few implementations, one tied to postgres/npgsql. I am wanting to avoid as much provider specific code as possible outside of our actual implementations, and since sometimes `service.Add` will be called just once with no other services it needed to be able to handle its own connection/trx etc.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other .NET database providers that behave differently - it is probably standard behavior to escalate to a distributed tx when more than one connection gets enlisted at the same time.